# What flavour of regular expression is grep?

Tags: grep

I'm guessing it's not a Perl Compatible Regular Expression, since there's a special kind of `grep` which is specifically PCRE. What's `grep` most similar to?

Are there any special quirks of `grep` that I need to know about? (I'm used to Perl and the `preg` functions in PHP)

Comment: It is worth noting that grep (and its several flavors of regexs) predates perl and php by a considerable period. The question isn't "Why doesn't grep do what per does?" but "Why did perl choose to do something different that grep?".

Comment: How do the answers on this page map to the options available in https://regex101.com/? I'd like to use that site to test my grep regex. The options there are `PCRE2`, `PCRE` `ECMA` `Python` `Golang` `Java 8`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Default GNU `grep` behavior is to use a slightly flavorful variant on [POSIX basic regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended), with a similarly tweaked species of [POSIX extended regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) for `egrep` (usually an alias for `grep -E`). POSIX ERE is what PHP [`ereg()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) uses.

GNU `grep` also claims to support `grep -P` for PCRE, by the way. So no terribly special kind of `grep` required.

Comment: I think GNU `grep` just support GNU BRE and GNU ERE. Because according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html POSIX BRE and POSIX ERE don’t support `\w` but GNU `grep` does.

Comment: The "special" grep he's referring to might be ack, which deserves mention.

Answer (score 9):

#### [POSIX BRE (Basic Regular Expressions)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

You can compare the various flavors [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

Answer (score 8):

There's a good write-up [here](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html). To quote the page, "grep is supposed to use BREs, except that grep -E uses EREs. (GNU grep fits some extensions in where POSIX leaves the behaviour unspecified)."

In other words, it's a long story. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Grep is an implementation of POSIX regular expressions.  There are two types of posix regular expressions -- basic regular expressions and extended regular expressions.  In grep, generally you use the -E option to allow extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The grep man pages do a pretty thorough job of explaining the flavor of regexp available in grep. `man grep` is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no regular grep function in PHP. If you are referring to the [ereg](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php) family of PHP functions then those are POSIX regular expressions. If you are referring to the Linux `grep` commandline utility, those are [POSIX regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX) as well. It supports both basic as well as extended POSIX regular expressions.