# Regular expression for unix config files

Tags: regex, grep

For a check if a variable are set or not in a known config file.

I need a regex that matches `var=1` but not `# var=1`. My tries doesn't work. Could me someone help, please?

`^(?<!#).*var.*` # matches both `var=1` and `# var=1`

EDIT: the follow regex solved the problem in a regex tester (regxlib.com) but grep doesn't find the line
`grep "^[^#].+(?<=var.*)" ~/testfile.conf`

testfile.conf
`#var=1
export var=2
export foo=2`

Does anybody know why this in grep doesn't work?

EDIT2:
The follow expressioon seems to solve my problem.

`grep "^[^#]*var" ~/testfile.conf` resp.
`sed -n "/^[^#]*var/p" ~/testfile.conf`

Comment: What did you tried? I think you mean `(?<!# )var=\d+`

Comment: What too are you using for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you specified.

```
/^[^#].+/gm
```

If you need "=" too, use this

```
/^[^#].+=.+/gm
```

Proof

http://www.regexr.com/3a1jp

---

EDIT after @mtm, that suggested to avoid pure spaces, so
 `/^[^#]*[^#\s]+\s*=\s*[^#\s]+/gm` [is another good choice](http://regexr.com/3a1oo). Remember that truncated declarations, as `foo = #123` are also invalid in a config file...

But if you using `grep` with *default regex*, the `+` is not an operator (must be escaped), and generic spaces need to be expressed by `[:space:]`. Some ways to use a complete regex,

```
grep "^[^#]*[^#[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[^#[:space:]]\+" config
grep -E "^[^#]*[^#[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[^#[:space:]]+" config
grep -P "^[^#]*[^#\s]+\s*=\s*[^#\s]+" config
```

more simple and precise is to check the real syntax of your config file,  perhaps `a@b,1=1` is invalid, so

```
grep -P "^\s*\w+\s*=\s*[^\s#]+" config
```

will be simple and a best choice.

Comment: thank you. I modified your suggestion - I think I need follow regex "^[^#].+(?<=var.*)" < #var=1 \n
var=2 \n
foo=2"

Comment: @Taiskorgon: you don't need to use a lookbehind. `/^ *var=.*/gm` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl Compatible Regular Expression, allowing spaces before and between the attribute name, then capturing both the name and the value.

```
/^\s*([\w]+)\s*=\s*(.+)/
```

As you have added that you are using `grep`, PCRE's can be run with `grep -P` if your `grep` supports that

The same in basic POSIX regex (that will run in most implementations of grep):

```
grep "^ *[_[:alnum:]]\+ *= *.\+" config
```

Comment: ... `grep` is POSIX, [you need `grep -P`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1074977/287948) to use PCRE